# terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException Error in my IOS Project

Tags: ios

I'm going along with the Udacity course where you have to make an app called Pitch Perfect where you record a sound, then play it fast, slow, high pitched, or low pitched. Problem is, on my screen when I press the pitch changing buttons the app crashes and the other ones don't do anything. This is my code in the play sounds view controller:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
class PlaySoundsViewController: UIViewController {
    var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer!
    var receivedAudio:RecordedAudio!
    var audioEngine:AVAudioEngine!
    var audioFile:AVAudioFile!
        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
            //if var filePath =  NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("movie_quote", ofType: "mp3"){
               // var filePathURL=NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)


          //  }else{
          //      println("The filepath could not be found.");
          //  }
            audioPlayer=AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: receivedAudio.filePathUrl, error: nil)
            audioPlayer.enableRate = true
            audioEngine=AVAudioEngine()
            audioFile=AVAudioFile(forReading: receivedAudio.filePathUrl,  error: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }





    func playAudioWithVariablePitch(pitch: Float){
        audioPlayer.stop()
        audioEngine.stop()
        audioEngine.reset()

        var audioPlayerNode=AVAudioPlayerNode()
        audioEngine.attachNode(audioPlayerNode)

        var changePitchEffect=AVAudioUnitTimePitch()
        changePitchEffect.pitch=pitch
        audioEngine.attachNode(changePitchEffect)

        audioEngine.connect(audioPlayerNode, to:changePitchEffect, format: nil)
        audioEngine.connect(changePitchEffect, to:audioEngine.outputNode, format: nil)

        audioPlayerNode.scheduleFile(audioFile, atTime: nil, completionHandler: nil)
        audioEngine.startAndReturnError(nil)
        audioPlayerNode.play()

    }


    @IBAction func playDarthVaderAudio(sender: UIButton) {
        audioPlayer.stop()
        audioEngine.stop()
        audioEngine.reset()
        playAudioWithVariablePitch(-1000)
    }

    @IBAction func playFastAudio(sender: UIButton) {
        audioPlayer.stop()
        audioEngine.stop()
        audioEngine.reset()
        audioPlayer.rate=2
        audioPlayer.currentTime=0.0
        audioPlayer.play()
        //Play audio quickly here!
    }
    @IBAction func playSlowAudio(sender: UIButton) {
        audioPlayer.stop()
        audioEngine.stop()
        audioEngine.reset()
        audioPlayer.rate=0.5
        audioPlayer.currentTime=0.0
        audioPlayer.play()
        //Play audio slooowllyy here.
    }


    @IBAction func playChipmunkAudio(sender: UIButton) {
        audioPlayer.stop()
        audioEngine.stop()
        audioEngine.reset()
        playAudioWithVariablePitch(1000)
    }

    @IBAction func stopAudio(sender: UIButton) {

        audioPlayer.stop()
        audioEngine.stop()
        audioEngine.reset()
    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on Stack Overflow. 
For more details see [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: Please post the stack trace from your crash

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it.